# Why Kotlin required put "==true" inside "if" verification with nullables var?

Tags: kotlin

folks!

We know, IF statement only works with true condition. The operator ? checks and guarantees firstName property is not null. So, if firstName isn't null and isEmpty() is also true, why "==true" is needed?

Shortly, why simple condition "**firstName?.isEmpty()**" is invalid?

```
class Person (firstName: String?) {
    init {
        if (firstName?.isEmpty() == true) {
            println("firstName is null")
        }else{
            println("The name is $firstName")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `firstName?.isEmpty()` to be, when `firstName` is `null`? Did you expect it to be true? Why?

Comment: firstName?.isEmpty() return a Boolean? and you can't use directly in a if statement. So using == true you are checking equality of a Boolean with a Boolean? witch is null safe so if firstName is null it will result to false.

Comment: alternatively, you can use firstName.isNullOrEmpty().

Comment: by the way, if `firstName` is null, the code above will go in the `else` branch, which is probably something you aren't expecting

Answer (score 3):

> The operator ? checks and guarantees firstName property is not null.

No, [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) operator doesn't guarantees this. It guarantees that you won't get `NullPointerException` if `firstName` is null, instead you will get `null` as a result of
`firstName?.isEmpty()` expression.

So, the type of this expression is `Boolean?`, and `if` condition must be `Boolean`.

I believe, you'd better use `firstName.isNullOrEmpty()` here.

Comment: Thank you! The best answer! Helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is because `firstName?.isEmpty()` can be `true`, `false`, or `null`.

`if (null)` does not make sense
*UNLESS* you are using a language that implicitly converts `null` to `true` or `false`.
Kotlin does not implicitly convert it.

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty will be called in this case only if firstName is not null

Answer (score 0):

Do note that the code does not work as intended (i.e. prints null if it is null or empty)
https://pl.kotl.in/H7rBIT8H6

```
fun main() {
    var firstName:String? = null
    
    if(firstName?.isEmpty() ==true){
        //print("firstName is null")
        print("test1: TRUE. ")   //<<-- THIS WILL NOT BE PRINTED
    }else {
        print ("test1: FALSE. ")   // <<-- THIS IS RETURNED INSTEAD
    }
    
    firstName = ""
     if(firstName?.isEmpty() ==true){
        print("test2: TRUE. ") //<<--WORKS AS INTENDED
    }else {
        print ("test2: FALSE. ")
    }
    
    firstName = "Hello"
    if(firstName?.isEmpty() ==true){
        print("test1: TRUE. ")
    }else {
        print ("test1: FALSE. ") //<<--WORKS AS INTENDED
    }
}
```

The output is

```
test1: FALSE. test2: TRUE. test1: FALSE.
```

notice "test1" is FALSE?

what is happening is the code

> "firstName?.isEmpty()" returns null if firstName is null.
> and consequently, "null == true" will return false

So instead, what you should do is either call

```
firstName.isNullOrEmpty()
```

or

```
firstName==null || firstName?.isEmpty()==true
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that your list is nullable. In Kotlin you should always avoid having nullable values. I would suggest refactoring.

Anyway, the answer is:

- Comparison needed because the list is nullable and you need a fallback because if the list is null, `isEmpty()` will not be called so you will not get a boolean value or condition which is needed for if.
- use `isNullOrEmpty()` instead